# how to change a dimension of array in python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am a newbie in python. I have a question about the dimension of array.

I have (10,192,192,1) array which type is (class 'numpy.ndarray').
I would like to divid this array to 10 separated array like 10 * (1,192,192,1). but I always got (192,192,1) array when I separate.
How can I get separated arrays as a same dimension type of original one?

below is my code.

```
b = np.ndarray((a.shape[0],a.shape[1],a.shape[2],a.shape[3]))
print(b.shape)  # (10,192,192,1)

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
b[i] = a[i]
print(b[i].shape)  # (192,192,1), but I want to get (1,192,192,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reshape it using `np.array()`

```
b = np.zeros((192,192,1))
print(b.shape)  #(192, 192, 1)
print(np.array([b]).shape) #(1, 192, 192, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the numpy `.reshape()` function:

```
b[i].reshape((1,192,192,1))
```

Check out the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

For example:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((13,24))
>>> x.shape
(13,24)
>>> x.resize((1,13,24)).shape
(1,13,24)
```